# "In State.php line 153 Area code is not set" error while upgrading to Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I tried to upgrade Magento core from 2.4.1 to 2.4.2 by changing composer.json and did composer install. After that, ran the upgrade command. The upgrade breaks and shows "***In vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php line 153 Area code is not set***". I went through various options, but couldn't find a proper way to fix it.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you change in the composer.json?

Comment: the version number alone

Comment: must be some extension upgraded along with magento and any 3rd party extension throwing error. please disable all 3rd party extension inside vendor folder.

Comment: @Max28 What did the resolution end up being for you on this? I'm currently experiencing the same issue

Comment: Am also facing the same issue when try to upgrade from Magento EE 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.2-p1

Comment: It might be due to a custom CLI command which is not setting properly the area. Also, if the command injects any other class in the constructor, the class must have the area set as well

Comment: @seeni Have you find out any solution for the same that you have commented on above I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

This error can be very frustated and you wont get specific magento var/logs or specific terminal outputs so the first thing you can do it is to force the area code setting area_global in the State.php constructor.

(magento purist read until the end)

In my version of magento i have:

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Config\ScopeInterface $configScope,
    $mode = self::MODE_DEFAULT
) {
    //$this->_areaCode = Area::AREA_GLOBAL; //EGS bypass upgrade
    $this->_configScope = $configScope;
    switch ($mode) {
        case self::MODE_DEVELOPER:
        case self::MODE_PRODUCTION:
        case self::MODE_DEFAULT:
            $this->_appMode = $mode;
            break;
        default:
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unknown application mode: {$mode}");
    }
}
```

After this you will be able to upgrade and have a better module error message on deployment.

!!! remember to delete the line you added to the core files.

Comment: It's not te best solution, but it worked for me :(

Comment: vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:91

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after upgrade to Magento2.4.3 but If I downgrade it to Magento2.4.1 it was not coming up so I've looked into the code and one of my custom module was causing it. so have a look at your modules (specifically look for the Console files) and disable the custom modules. This way you can deal with this, I'd not recommend changing directly State.php